# how to debug in silverlight4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

VS 2010 ,c# silverlight 4, RIA, MVVM light

i moved my SL4 app to another folder, now I cannot debug it. (use to debug fine)

the break point is dimmed with a yellow "warning" icon 
 "No symbols have been loaded for this document".

where shall I look in order to fix it ?

the web project is my start up prj, and the testPage.aspx is set as start page.

thanks
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable 'Silverlight' debugging in the properties for your main web project.  It's a checkbox that everyone misses.  Right-click the project in the explorer and it should be at the bottom of the second or third tab.

Specifically:

1. Pull up properties on your web project
2. Select the 'Web' tab
3. Scroll down and enable the Silverlight debugger via the checkbox

If that still isn't working, make sure you're running with debugging (F5, not Ctrl+F5).

Comment: If that doesn't work, you should also make sure the application is set to debug. In the Silverlight applications tab of the properties, remove and re-add your silverlight app. Check debug there as well.

Comment: Thanks FGhilardi...your right the check box was on ASP.NET not SILVERLIGHT
once I checked it, debugging check points are back and working.
thanks Kevin, I guess that is a trick...(the re-add ?)